# How can I picture antisymmetry of the Lie derivative?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

It's obvious that the Lie derivative defined in terms of Lie brackets is anti-symmetric. But what is an intuitive way to visualize the anti-symmetry in the 'differentiating along a flow' definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whichever definition you use that involves differentiating along a flow, it ought to have the property that $L_X X = 0$; in other words, for reasons that should be clear, the Lie derivative is alternating. In the presence of bilinearity, this is equivalent to antisymmetry.